# Trying to grab rows out of database where date is today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason, my @sub_opps is resulting in:
 ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_SubOpp.

This means my .each statement produces nothing, obviously.  I've tried multiple things but can't find the correct tweak to make this work.

Any idea why?

```
def index
    @sub_opps = SubOpp.where("status = ? AND sub_time = ?", false, Date.today)
end
```

To clarify a few things, sub_time is a column in my SubOpp model and is datetime.  Status is boolean.  So, i am trying to show SubOpp rows whose status is false and whose datetime is today.

Here is my view.

```
<% @sub_opps.each do |sub_opp| %>
  <%= render sub_opp, :sub_opp => :sub_opp %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks

Comment: sorry - see updated post.  i changed it based on one of the answers below and missed that.

Comment: Just checking: what is the data type of `sub_time` in your database? And what do you get if you run just one of these conditions on the query individually?

Comment: sub_time is 'datetime' in the database.  i believe this is the issue.  when i test and make sub_opps just values that are false i get results.  when i test and make sub_opps just values whose dates are today, i get the issue i'm experiencing.  i do have rows in the database that have both of these conditions so it should show results.

Comment: Why do you expect `@sub_opps` to be anything else? Does your `@sub_opps.each` work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  The issue is that datetime columns in a model contain both a date and a time, so trying to query rows out of this model where their datetime equals today's date was not going to work.  To solve this, I did the following in the controller.

```
@sub_opps = SubOpp.where('sub_time BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day).all
```

This grabs all the SubOpp's where the time is between the beginning and end of the day.  Again, underlying issue is datetime is date AND time, so comparing just to a date did not produce any results.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax for `where` is off...try this:

```
@sub_opps = SubOpp.where("status = ? AND sub_time = ?", false, Date.today)
```